# Making two columns unique when jointly compounded using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-3.1

I have two columns called *Monkey* and *Donkey*. Both are non-empty, i.e. `null` is not allowed. The setup is declared as follows.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(builder);
  ...
  builder.Entity<Thing>()
    .Property(a => a.Monkey)
    .IsRequired();
  builder.Entity<Thing>()
    .Property(a => a.Donkey)
    .IsRequired();
}
```

Now, I learned that the combined content must be unique, i.e. no record may have the same monkey and donkey. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties?redirectedfrom=MSDN#configuring-an-index-on-one-or-more-properties) (index on multiple props), I'm supposed to use `HasColumnAnnotation` and pass an instance of `IndexAnnotation`. It's also suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47718780/1525840) to use `IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName` from `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Annotations`.

The problem is that I can't find that method and instead only see `HasAnnotation`. It's unclear to me if it's a more recent version (as the post linked to is a bit dated by now). I can't access the namespace *Entity* in the `using` statement, neither.

```
builder.Entity<Thing>()
  .Property(a => a.Monkey)
  .HasAnnotation(...);
```

Is that the right approach or should I continue looking for the other annotation method? What is missing to get the namespace in? Is indexing the appropriate way to go to begin with?

I also tried with index but that requires me to declare a specialized class, which seems clunky and suggests it's the wrong way to go.

```
builder.Entity<Thing>()
  .HasIndex(a => new IndexDedicatedClass(a.Monkey, a.Donkey))
  .IsUnique();
```

Comment: ASP.NET Core 3.1 ships only with EF Core 3.1, MSDN link is for EF6, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=fluent-api#composite-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a composite index that spans multiple columns, then mark it as unique, which creates a unique index on the DB.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Thing>(builder =>
{
    builder
        .HasIndex(e => new { e.Monkey, e.Donkey })
        .IsUnique();
});
```

This in effect helps ensure that no `($monkey, $donkey)` tuple appear twice in the table.

### Further info

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=fluent-api#composite-index

Comment: Ah, I was into that approach but didn't realize I could use an anonymous class for that purpose. Now that I see it, it's kind of obvious. I guess I got stuck in the hard-type-thinking. Is such an approach impacting heavily on the performance or is it precisely equivalent to setting a composite key using pure SQL?

Comment: It translates to pure SQL. Generate a migration, then its sql script, you'll see a `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX $name ON $table($col1, $col2)` statement.